# Retrieve record where a date is between start and end dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have searched for similar questions but what I found is quite different from what I am trying to achieve.

I'm trying to get the status of a given day which would be in the range of days between the start and end dates in the db.

Records:

```
#<Schedule id: 1, starts_at: "2015-10-03", ends_at: "2015-10-15", status: "Available">

#<Schedule id: 2, starts_at: "2015-10-16", ends_at: "2015-10-30", status: "Busy">
```

what is the best way to retrieve the status of the day where the date is "2015-10-9"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `schedule.starts_at` and `schedule.ends_at` are formatted date :

```
date = Date.new(2015, 10, 9)

# matching_date is going to return us the schedules where the date is matched 
matching_dates = schedule.select{|schedule| schedule.starts_at < date && schedule.ends_at > date}

# now, the map method is going to return us the status for every given matching_dates
statuses = matching_dates.map(&:status)
```

Note that I speak in plural for `matching_dates` and `statuses`, because the `select` method return us an array of all matching dates.

We could (and should, I guess :) ) do it by having a `where` clause on our Schedule, which might be better, but less explicit in my opinion. Either way, we'll get a collection of matching dates.

Comment: yeah that was my problem I've been trying to use a `where` clause but hey I like this solution, perfect. thank you very much :)